# Why do I keep getting the same first digit while I've seeded a generator with time?

Tags: c++

I don't understand why I keep getting the same 1st digit when I've already seeded a `default_random_engine` with `time(0)`(*C++ Primer* tell me to use`time(0)`). Is it a problem of my computer? (Ubuntu, C++11)

I tried on a online compiler and it's interesting that I got the same 1st digit using `gcc` while not using `clang++`.

https://wandbox.org/permlink/kiUg1BW1RkDL8y8c

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <random>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    auto t = time(0);
    cout << "time: " << t << endl;
    default_random_engine e(t);
    uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist(0, 9);
    cout << "sequence:";
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        cout << uniform_dist(e);
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

As you can see I keep getting `6` as the first digit of a random number, no matter I use `clang++` or `g++` to compile. 
[image]

Comment: Interesting. I got 6 as well on the wandbox

Comment: @drescherjm Yes.. Try `clang` it gives you a whole random sequence. But `clang` fails on my computer..

Comment: That's one of the problems with [random number generators](http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25), especially with such a limited set of numbers to choose from. You could probably improve it by using a better engine (like `mt19937`). I also suggest you see [the example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution#Example) in [this `uniform_int_distribution` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Hmm. I tried 2 combinations. 1. Enlarge `(0, 9)` to `(0, 10000)` don't change anything. 2. Replace `time(0) ` with `random_device`, it works. Interesting.

Comment: Using `time(0)` the seed values aren't that different, unlike using `std::random_device`. If you still wanted to use `time(0)` you could call `e.discard(n);` where `n` is the number of steps you want to advance the generator's state. If effect, throwing away the initial `n` values.

Comment: If `std::default_random_engine` is implemented as `rand`, then `time(0)` is not going to produce vastly different seeds which will lead to a random sequence that is close the the last one.  Stay away from `std::default_random_engine` as you don't know what it is.  Unless you really need performance I would default to using a `std::mt19937` as your go to PRNG

Comment: Btw, 3. Replace `default_random_engine` with `std::mt19937` also works..

Comment: Not the same but close.  `1541162550` is not much different from `1541162552` which can really matter with a bad PRNG

Comment: @Blastfurnace I don't understand. `std::default_random_engine e(x)`, `x` is what I am told as `seed`. As you can see from the result picture, each time the `time`(seed) is different.

Comment: Just looking at your screenshot, the time values are fairly close to each other. So it's not completely surprising that the generator began in a similar state. That's why `time(0)` isn't a great source of entropy.

Comment: @Blastfurnace So are you saying that different seed may result in same (middle or final)value? `seed value = f(seed)`. I don't know the conversion but a sort of `many to one` thing?

Comment: It really depends on the generator. It's conceivable that the most-significant bits of the seed have a greater effect on the generator's initial state. My advice, use a better seed like `std::random_device` and maybe use `discard()` to "warm up" the generator before use.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Ok, thanks guys. This is beyond my exploration. I would just take `std::random_device`.

Comment: Don't edit answers into questions.  Instead accept answers by giving them a checkmark.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Ok. But I've seen many questions including answers... So I just...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You are setting initial states into your random-generator that are very similar.  Depending on the quality of the generator, this may or may not result in similar outputs.  To illustrate, I've augmented your sample to (a) print only the first sequence, since that is what we care about, and (b) print several results of various resolution:

```
int main(){
    auto t = time(0);
    cout << "time: " << t << endl;
    default_random_engine e(t);
    default_random_engine e2(t);
    default_random_engine e3(t);
    default_random_engine e4(t);
    uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist(0, 9);
    uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist2(0,999);
    uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist3(0,99999);
    uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist4(0,9999999);
    cout << "sequence: ";
    cout << uniform_dist(e) << " " << uniform_dist2(e2) << " " << uniform_dist3(e3) << " " << uniform_dist4(e4);
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When run:

```
$ ./a.out
time: 1541162210
sequence: 7 704 70457 7070079
$ ./a.out
time: 1541162211
sequence: 7 704 70457 7070157
$ ./a.out
time: 1541162212
sequence: 7 704 70458 7070236
$ ./a.out
time: 1541162213
sequence: 7 704 70459 7070315
$ ./a.out
time: 1541162214
sequence: 7 704 70460 7070393
$ ./a.out
time: 1541162215
sequence: 7 704 70461 7070472
$ ./a.out
time: 1541162216
sequence: 7 704 70461 7070550
$ ./a.out
time: 1541162217
sequence: 7 704 70462 7070629
$ ./a.out
time: 1541162218
sequence: 7 704 70463 7070707
$ ./a.out
time: 1541162219
sequence: 7 704 70464 7070786
```

While I do not know exactly what this random-generator implementation is doing, you can easily see that it is performing a very simple transformation of your seed into state, and state into output values.  As other comments have suggested, there are better random generators and better seeds.  Also note that the quality varies between implementations; Visual Studio 2017 does not exhibit this behavior.

Comment: Dude, this experiment is so smart and straightforward. Very comprehensive, thanks.

Comment: As a slight improvement, time(0) could be fed into std::mt19937 (EDIT: I now see that pretty much everyone else has already recommended this).

Comment: In g++ and clang++ on x86_64, `std::default_random_engine` is a typedef for `std::linear_congruential_engine<long unsigned int, 16807, 0, 2147483647>`.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in comments, [std::random_device](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) will provide a superior source of seed material compared to `time()`.

However, if there is a need to use a small seed with a linear congruential generator, the seed value can be expanded to make a better initializer. Linear generators are slow in redistributing the bits in the seed value, so a small difference will cause the initial few values to be close to each other.

The standard library provides [std::seed_seq](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/seed_seq) which will expand a small seed to a better initializer value:

```
seed_seq seed({t});
default_random_engine e(seed);
```